# I have a separate boot and system partition, now I can't boot into the system partition

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

I have Windows 7 on my disk **C**. Then dual booted it with Linux Mint. I removed linux mint and accidentally forgot to remove grub (which was installed by Linux Mint) so grub went into rescue mode. What I did was install Windows XP on another partition, **F** (since I didn't want to lose all the files in my Windows 7 Partition). How do I get to boot back into my Windows 7 disk? I also tried to install UNetbootin but it seems to install the bootloader on my C partition intead of my F one.

Here's how it looks like,

[image]